# Core Data didselectatrow updating text field

Tags: swift

I have a tableview which presents custom cells to the user that on their selection changes text.label depending on their selection. I have tried various methods but using the code list below doesn't work. I have tried multiple methods to get this work. What happens for this is if I select the 1 cell presented then every 10 cell or so is selected instead of just the one selected. I tried to use:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var myDeckCards: DeckCards?
    let listed = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Cards

    // check: is there already a DeckCards object for this Card and this Deck?
    let deckCardsSet = listed.cardselections
    println("The set of DeckCards for that Card is \(deckCardsSet.count)")
    for eachDeckCard in listed.cardselections {
        let myDeckCard = eachDeckCard as! DeckCards
        if myDeckCard.cardsstored == passedDeckObject {
            // There is already a DeckCard object for this Card and currentDeck
            myDeckCards = eachDeckCard as? DeckCards
        }
    }
    if myDeckCards == nil {
        // There is no DeckCard object for this Card and currentDeck
        // So create one...
        myDeckCards = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("DeckCards", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!) as? DeckCards
        myDeckCards!.cardsselected = listed
        myDeckCards!.cardsstored = passedDeckObject!
    }
    // your code to determine numberSelected here; I'll assume 2!
    cardCount = myDeckCards!.numberSelected.integerValue
    deckCardCount = myDeckCards!.deckcardCount.integerValue
    cardCount = cardCount == 2 ? 0 : cardCount + 1
    println(deckCardCount)
    println(cardCount)
    myDeckCards!.numberSelected = cardCount
    let indexPathUpdate: AnyObject = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath.row)
    let currentCell = cardsListed.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPathUpdate) as! firstCardDetails?
      //firstCardDetails customtableviewcellcontroller//
        if currentCell!.selected == true {
            if cardCount == 0 {
                currentCell!.cardCounter.text = "  "
            } else {
                if cardCount == 1 {
                    currentCell!.cardCounter.text = "  1"
                } else {
                    if cardCount == 2 {
                        currentCell!.cardCounter.text = "  2"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As requested this is the cellForRowAtIndexPath func:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: firstCardDetails = cardsListed.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! firstCardDetails
    let listed = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Cards

    cell.cardName?.text = listed.name as String
    if listed.cardType.isEqualToValue(1) {
        cell.cardAttack?.text = "*"
    } else {
        if listed.cardType.isEqualToValue(2) {
            cell.cardAttack?.text = "*"
        } else {
    cell.cardAttack?.text = listed.attack.stringValue
    }
    }
    if listed.cardType.isEqualToNumber(1) {
        cell.cardHealth?.text = "*"
    } else {
        if listed.cardType.isEqualToValue(2) {
            cell.cardHealth?.text = "*"
        } else {
    cell.cardHealth?.text = listed.health.stringValue
    }
    }
    cell.cardCost?.text = listed.cost.stringValue

        if listed.cardType.isEqualToNumber(0) {
            cell.cardType?.text = "Minion"
        } else {
            if listed.cardType.isEqualToNumber(1) {
                cell.cardType?.text = "Spell"
            } else {
                if listed.cardType.isEqualToNumber(2) {
                cell.cardType?.text = "Weapon"
            }
            }
    }
    if listed.rarity.isEqualToNumber(1) {
        cell.rarityType?.text = "Legendary"
        cell.rarityType?.textColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    } else {
        if listed.rarity.isEqualToNumber(2) {
            cell.rarityType?.text = "Epic"
            cell.rarityType?.textColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
        } else {
            if listed.rarity.isEqualToNumber(3) {
                cell.rarityType?.text = "Rare"
                cell.rarityType?.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            } else {
                if listed.rarity.isEqualToNumber(4) {
                    cell.rarityType?.text = "Common"
                    cell.rarityType?.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
                } else {
                    if listed.rarity.isEqualToNumber(5) {
                        cell.rarityType?.text = "Starter"
                        cell.rarityType?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if listed.cardClass.isEqualToNumber(1) {
        cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0xbe/255, green: 0x23/255, blue: 0x0f/255, alpha: 1.0)
    } else {
        if listed.cardClass.isEqualToNumber(2) {
            cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        } else {
            if listed.cardClass.isEqualToNumber(3) {
                cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0xE2/255, green: 0xA8/255, blue: 0x79/255, alpha: 1.0)
            } else {
                if listed.cardClass.isEqualToNumber(4) {
                    cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0xFF/255, green: 0xAA/255, blue: 0x00/255, alpha: 1.0)
                } else {
                    if listed.cardClass.isEqualToNumber(5) {
                        cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0x22/255, green: 0x63/255, blue: 0x29/255, alpha: 1.0)
                    } else {
                        if listed.cardClass.isEqualToNumber(6) {
                            cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor.brownColor()
                        } else {
                            if listed.cardClass.isEqualToNumber(7) {
                                cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0xBB/255, green: 0x76/255, blue: 0xE4/255, alpha: 1.0)
                            } else {
                                if listed.cardClass.isEqualToNumber(8) {
                                    cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0x9E/255, green: 0xB5/255, blue: 0xFF/255, alpha: 1.0)
                                } else {
                                    if listed.cardClass.isEqualToNumber(9) {
                                        cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
                                    } else {
                                        if listed.cardClass.isEqualToNumber(10) {
                                            cell.cardName?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                                        }
                                        }
                                }
                            }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

as a means to create the indexpath referenced to define which cell is actually being selected but this isn't quite correct. There is very little online covering doing this for core data objects. It functions correctly when not core data but not with core data. Any insights into this and why I need to do it would be appreciated as I am still learning the ins and outs of programming in general!

Comment: Try this `let indexPathUpdate = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath.row)`

Comment: i get a error using that line that states that cannot invoke 'objectAtIndexPath' with an argument list of type '(Int)' and the current cell asks that i change indexPathUpdate as NSIndexPath

Comment: can you post your whole code

Comment: i updated to the entire did selectatrow method

Comment: firstCardDetails is the controller for the custom cell that i created that i am trying to update the label in during the didselectatrow method

Comment: I am at a complete loss as I have tried about everything I can think of to actually fix this.

Comment: whats the error you are getting

Comment: the most recent attempt at fixing this with a different method that yielded the same error was Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x4)

Comment: Basically I have 500 objects presenting and I want my custom cell to only update the text field showing the number of objects selected when the cell is selected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89081/discussion-between-matthew-and-lamar).

Comment: Can you show the cellForRowAtIndexPath code as well - this looks like a cell reuse problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem with cell reuse - cells that scroll off screen are placed in a queue and are pulled off the queue for rows scrolling on screen.  Any changes made to the cell before it is scrolled off screen are (by default) not reset, so those changes remain when you dequeue them for a different row.

You need to ensure that your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code makes the relevant changes.  Copy the key bits of code:

```
var myDeckCards: DeckCards?
var cardCount = 0
let listed = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Cards
for eachDeckCard in listed.cardselections {
    let myDeckCard = eachDeckCard as! DeckCards
    if myDeckCard.cardsstored == passedDeckObject {
        myDeckCards = eachDeckCard as? DeckCards
        cardCount = myDeckCards!.numberSelected.integerValue
    }
}
if cardCount == 0 {
    cell.cardCounter.text = "  "
    } else {
        if cardCount == 1 {
            cell.cardCounter.text = "  1"
        } else {
            if cardCount == 2 {
                cell.cardCounter.text = "  2"
        }
    }
}
```

from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, delete the `indexPathUpdate` var and just use `indexPath`.

Also, just to note those nested if statements are a prime candidate for switch/case.

Comment: Following this advice has yielded a different result now. Instead of selecting just 1 row it will now select all rows the first cells presented.